# can a table row be targeted by the bgcolor or its value with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html on page along with other code on the page. This is inside a table along with other table rows. I would like to target only this tr so I can change the color. I do not have access to the code and because the amount of tr's can vary within this table css would be difficult. Is it possible to target this tr by the css bgcolor and change it to something else?

```
<tr bgcolor="#009900"> 
        <td width="90"><b><font color="#ffffff">Total:</font></b></td>
        <td width="70"><b><font color="#ffffff">1</font></b></td>
        <td width="70"><b><font color="#ffffff">0</font></b></td>
        <td width="70"><b><font color="#ffffff">0</font></b></td>
        <td width="144"><b><font color="#ffffff">$0.00</font></b></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jQuery to target the row by it's background color and change it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tr = $('tr[bgcolor="#009900"]')
tr.css('background-color', '#000000');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to test it at the moment, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
$("tr[bgcolor='#009900']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("bgcolor", "#ffffff");
});
```